# Making a scrollable bootstrap table using data from database

Tags: css

My problem is this - I am populating a table with data from my database but I want a scrollable table to make it look neater. I have tried the following code but it is not working. First the html markup (this works):

```
echo '<div  class="container"><table class="table table-responsive">';
        echo '<thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Item ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Item Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>
            <th scope="col">Condition</th>
            <th scope="col">User First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">User Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Date Entered</th>
            <th scope="col">Date Retired</th>
            <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
            <th scope="col">Comments</th>
            </tr>
        </thead><tbody>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

          echo '<tr><td>'. $row['ItemID'].'</td><td>' . 
      $row['ItemType'].'</td><td>'. $row['Model'].'</td><td>'. 
      $row['Condition'].'</td><td>'. $row['UserFirstName'].'</td><td>'. 
      $row['UserLastName'].'</td><td>'. $row['DateEntered'] ;
          echo '</td><td>' . $row['RetiredDate'].'</td><td>' . 
      $row['Supplier'].'</td><td>' . $row['Comments'].'</td><tr>';
         }


        echo '<tbody></table></div>';
```

and my CSS is:

```
      tr {
width: 100%;
display: inline-table;
}

table{
 height:500px; 
}
tbody{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
th{
  border: 1px solid #006622;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
td{
  border: 0.5px solid #006622;
  min-width: 95px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

It seems the table is not following the CSS rules I have added. My style sheet is linked and is placed after the bootstrap link so it isn't that. Any suggestions thanks

Comment: I recomend you datatables plugin. https://datatables.net/

Comment: Tried that and even though the CSS styles were showing the scrolling did not work. I have a suspicious feeling that it has to do with the php.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to help you with your code, but i believe that I can also help you this way. In plugin I mentioned - You are able to set number of rows displayed on first page and you are able to enable X or Y  scroll. Documentation examples in links 
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html   
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: I have solved it just had to chane the tbody CSS to tbody.scrollTable{
 display: block;
 height: 500px;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 100%
}